# Ruby on Rails: Assigning attribute values to generic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generics, model, attributes

I am trying to write a ruby on rails function that will create a new object for any model. Here is what I have so far

```
def create_populated_object(model)
        test_object = model.new
        model.columns.each do |column|
            attr_name = column.name
            attr_type = column.type

            #test_object.assign_attributes(attr_name+':'+ "9")
            puts "#{':'+attr_name} => #{attr_type}"

            if attr_type.to_s == 'integer'
                b = '{:' + attr_name.to_s + '=>' + 9.to_s + '}'
                puts b
                test_object.assign_attributes(b)
                puts "it worked"
            elsif attr_type.to_s == 'string'
                puts "string"
            elsif attr_type.to_s == 'datetime'
                puts "date time"
            elsif attr_type.to_s == 'boolean'
                puts "boolean"
            elsif attr_type.to_s == 'text'
                puts "text"
            else
                puts "UNKNOWN ATTRIBUTE TYPE"
            end

        end

        puts test_object
    end
```

In my example, id is the first attribute of the model. I try to assign the value 9 to it, but I keep getting this error:

NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "{:id=>9}":String

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Always give everything involved in a minimal example of the problem. Here, code and database state for the assignment and anything else to explain "I try to assign the value 9 to it". Read help re asking good questions. (Even if it turns out there is enough in this particular question for a solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assign_attributes` expects a hash of attributes to be passed to it. You are passing it a string. Would it be problematic to simply say b = {attr_name.to_sym => 9}?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send a `Hash` object instead of a string to the method:

```
b = { attr_name => 9 }
test_object.assign_attributes(b)
```